# Cannot Populate UICollectionView with Firebase Data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, firebaseui

I have a Firebase Database and am using the `FirebaseUI` for iOS. That database contains information I want to use to populate a UICollectionView:

[image]

Below is my ViewController Code that is currently generating an error "Cannot Assign value of type FUICollectionViewDataSource":

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseDatabaseUI

private let reuseIdentifier = "PollCell"

class TrendingViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var dataSource: FUITableViewDataSource!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes

    self.dataSource = self.collectionView?.bind(to: self.ref) { collectionView, indexPath, snap in
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        /* populate cell */
        return cell
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
       }
  }
```

[image]

Essentially, I wanted to populate the customer cell with the data in Firebase, it will be several `Labels` and an `ImageView`. Here is the custom cell I created:

```
import UIKit

class PollCell: UICollectionViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                  for: indexPath) as! PollCell

    return cell
   } 

}
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated as I am unable to understand how to essentially

Comment: Instead of var dataSource: FUITableViewDataSource!  , use FUICollectionViewDataSource in variable declaration

Comment: read more on https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseDatabaseUI

Comment: The second error you are having is because you are writing a collectionview datasource method inside a collectonview cell. Its wrong to dequeue the cell in the class itself thats why it shows override error.

Comment: Jen - where do I add that override method then? Outside the class? It should inherit from UICollectionViewCell I presume?